# How can I create a MariaDB TLS connection with `mysql_async`

Tags: rust, mariadb

I want to connect my database to Rust. I have 3 certificate files (client, ca, key). But I do not get any connection. I tried the following SSL options. And get different warnings. I tried with `rustls-tls` and with `native-tls`, nothing is working. Were is my issue about using the certificates?
Warning I get with `rustls-tls`:

1. ```
   called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Io(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error:       InvalidCertificate(Other(UnsupportedCertVersion)) }))
   ```
2. ```
   called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Tls(Tls(InvalidCertificate(BadEncoding))))
   ```

With `native-tls`:

1. ```
   called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Tls(TlsError(Os { code: -2146893018, kind: Uncategorized, message: "The format of the received message was unexpected or incorrect." })))
   ```
2. ```
   called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Tls(TlsError(Os { code: -2146881269, kind: Uncategorized, message: "ASN1 Invalid license plate value." })))
   ```

SSL Options I tried in various combinations.

My Database is Maria DB 10.x and the Cert files work with MySQL Workbench and Heidi_SQL

```rust
let ssl_opts = SslOpts::default()
    .with_danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
    .with_client_identity(Some(ClientIdentity::new(
        Path::new("/src/ssl2/client-cert.pem"),
        Path::new("/src/ssl2/client-key.pem"),
    )))
    .with_client_identity(Some(ClientIdentity::new(
        Path::new("/src/ssl2/ca-cert.pem"),
        Path::new("/src/ssl2/ca-key.pem"),
    )))
    .with_client_identity(Some(ClientIdentity::new(
        Path::new("/src/ssl2/server-cert.pem"),
        Path::new("/src/ssl2/server-key.pem"),
    )));

let ssl_opts = SslOpts::default()
    .with_danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
    .with_client_identity(Some(
        ClientIdentity::new(Path::new("/src/ssl2/client-identity.p12"))
            .with_password("Password"),
    ))
    .with_root_cert_path(Some(Path::new("/src/ssl2/client-cert.pem")))
    .with_root_cert_path(Some(Path::new("/src/ssl2/client-key.pem")))
    .with_root_cert_path(Some(Path::new("/src/ssl2/ca-cert.pem")))
    .with_root_cert_path(Some(Path::new("/src/ssl2/ca-key.pem")));

let ssl_opts = SslOpts::default()
    .with_danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
    .with_client_identity(Some(
        ClientIdentity::new(Path::new("/src/ssl2/client-identity.p12"))
            .with_password("Password"),
    ));
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Logic queston for you, How should sombody who do not understand what is going on and has maybe missing information should write the correct question? I setup the link without sslOpts and it works fine. I use certificates in other mysql connections and it works fine. So what should i ask more than that i need help to understand what my question should be? I do not know what is going on here and thats why i need helpt to understand.  When you hit by a bullet you also not say: I was hit by a bullet, please, cann you tell me how i can fix my sinus node on my heart, and get my chest repair?

Comment: @RunDosRun I don't see how being unfarmiliar with the topic prevents you from omitting statements completely devoid of any information like "Can someone help me?" instead of asking specific questions about what you do and don't understand about the error messages.

Comment: The Thin is that i'm confused and don't know where to start. I have a fundamentel understanding error here. Everything works fine alone, but when i combine them there is an issue. And i do not know where to start? Rad tons of skript and nothing realy descripe how basic insallation is working. A lot of things are also confusing. In Mariadb in manual you have [client-mariadb] in ini files you find only [client]

Comment: `rustls-tls` isn't a crate published on https://crates.io did you mean `rustls`?

Comment: thank you for the question. rutls is an connection option inside mysql_async. It is build on rustls-tls.